# Bus error in manipulating virtual addresses

Tags: c, linux, memory, memory-address

I wrote a small piece of code in C to try out how virtual memory protection mechanisms actually work in Linux. I used Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

So, I write a program that reads its own virtual memory mappings in `/proc/pid/maps` file.
Then, the program starts to parse that file and extracts address ranges and permissions.
For mappings with read permission, the program dumps the content in hex format, and for write permission it writes arbitrary content in random location chosen between `base` and `limit` addresses.
I understand why the programs receives "Segmentation Fault" when it writes in arbitrary location. 
But for read permission, I cannot explain why the program receives a **"Bus error"** signal upon execution even with aligned attribute for pointer variables used to hold virtual addresses.
Here is the `dump` function I wrote:

```
void dump(char *base, char *limit) {
    char *p __attribute__ ((aligned (1))); // Enforce address alignment by the compiler
    for (p = base; p < limit; p = p + 0x1) 
        printf("%x", (char)(*p));
    printf("\n");
}
```

Another question: any idea to modify memory with execute (and write) permissions by "injecting" some crafted code?

Comment: Do you think the address mappings read from /proc/pid/maps remain unchanged while your program executes? Show a [mre]. Incidentally, you should declare `p` (and the other pointers) as `unsigned char *p` and print it with `printf("%hhx", *p);`, to avoid issues with signedness. Declaring a `char` (or `unsigned char`) as `aligned (1)` would have no effect on a `char`, since the alignment of `char` is necessarily 1. However, you are declaring the pointer `p` as having an alignment of 1, rather than the `char` it points to, and that is not what you want.

Comment: Yes, I think memory mappings do not change during execution, at least for statically linked and loaded small program. For type declaration, I agree that `unsigned char` is better, but I do not understand why the `char` should be aligned? I am interesting to the address not data.

Comment: A `char` object is one byte. The alignment requirement of a `char` object is one byte. Asking the compiler to make the alignment requirement of a `char` object one byte changes nothing because it is already one byte. However, the declaration `char *p __attribute__ ((aligned (1)));` does not request an alignment requirement of one byte for the `char` objects. It requests an alignment requirement of one byte for the pointer `p`. There is no point to that; `p` does not need to have any particular alignment for the purposes you use it for. Simply declare `p` with `unsigned char *p`.

Comment: I see. Actually, I have done that after getting the bus error to avoid misalignment that could be behind that error. Initially, I used `unsigned long` type to hold read data (for efficiency), but when I got the error I changed to `char`.